# BufferedReader виснет после ввода первой строки и заполняет внутренний массив пустыми строками. код же очень примитивен, в чем дело?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = null;
        String app;
//==================================================================================
        while ((app = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
            s+=app ;
        }//заполняет внутренний массив ридера нулями
        или
        while (reader.ready()) {
            s+=app;
        }//всегда false, цикл даже не начинается
//==================================================================================
        System.out.println("Мы считали с клавиатуры эту строку:");
        System.out.println(s);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправил код, в соответствии вашему комментарию как должна работать программа. Обратите внимание на условие **while**. Я там использую пустую строку для выхода из цикла, потому что ваш цикл с **null** будет бесконечный, так как вы никогда не введете **null** через консоль. (Пустая строчка это не **null**)

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = "";
        String app;

        while (!(app = reader.readLine()).equals("")) {
            s += app;
        }


        System.out.println("Мы считали с клавиатуры эту строку:");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: программа по сути должна работать очень просто.
прочесть все строки, что вводит юзер, и затем их вывести одной строкой из StringBuilder'а

первый ваш вариант работает как надо,

а вот второй выдает вот это
str1

str2

Мы считали с клавиатуры эту строку:

str1

Comment: `//а если перенести вывод за тело цикла, то цикл становится бесконечным
//но ведь по условию, он должен останавливаться, если юзер ввел пустую
//строку
//почему то условие работает только если в цикле есть вывод`

Comment: почему вот такой цикл бесконечный?
`while ((app = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s += app;
         }`

Comment: Пустая строка "" и null - это разные понятия. String str = null; - переменная ссылается на "ничто". String str = ""; это уже совершенно другое дело, и переменная ссылается на пустую строку.

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ в соответствии с описанным принципом работы программы.

Comment: я с вами полностью согласен, но отмечу, что в не очень далеком прошлом, null таки работал как пустая строка из консоли,
НО МОЙ ВОПРОС В ДРУГОМ.
и я буду очень признателен, если вы сможете мне помочь.
Ваш код я тупо скопипастил и запустил.
и вот тут кроется проблема.
В IntellijIDEA он работает криво!!
А вот в онлайн компиляторе так как и должен))
И я никак не могу понять в чем дело.
В идее результат работы таков, что чтение заканчивается после ввода второй строки, и программа выводит "Мы считали с клавиатуры эту строку:" + ПЕРВАЯ ВВЕДЕННАЯ СТРОКА

Comment: Вторая просто отбрасывается
Но мало того, что она отбрасывается, так ведь и прога сама по себе останавливается, хотя пустую строку никто не вводил.
я не понимаю как два компилятора могут выдавать разный результат.
жава 17 стоит

Comment: Тогда, вынужден капитулировать. У меня также InteliijIDEA и программа отрабатывает нормально. Запускал множество раз, output всегда был корректный. Не смог отловить несанкционированное "останавливание" программы

Comment: я заметил одну странную вещь - программа работает нормально в том случае, если я ввожу строку, начиная со второй включительно, предварительно затерев предыдущую в консоли.
 То есть я не могу их по очереди писать просто отделяя с помощью Enter
Нужно именно затереть предыдущую и написать на ее место следующую строку.

**Вам такое поведение не знакомо??**
Может это какие то приколы идеи?
А то в некоторых моментах, после обновления до 17 jdk, идея стала вести себя как то странно, в частности поменяла шаблонное поведения конструкций типа try-catch